# Why does CSS border overlapping make the border look thicker?

Tags: html, css

The code:
http://jsfiddle.net/s08nypfd/62/

Border for inner block is overlapping and looks very thick,
is there a solution?
It renders differently in Firefox and Chrome.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_block{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background:#888;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: This happens because the "block" is nested inside the "main_block", and so that's exactly what you see.  Can you be more specific about what you want it to look like instead?

Comment: check the element for class block. it looks very thick.. i want to fix that.

Answer (score 6):

Set the `margin-*` values on `.block`:

```
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8tzxLm7/)

Comment: I just tested in Firefox and it looks the same as in Chrome. What version? I'm at 50.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to play around `box-sizing` attribute. If you set negative margins as advised somwhere, desing will crash just if you change thickness of border.

Also you can use a little trick for main_block - set `border: none` and set inset box-shadow instead of border.

You need to set `box-sizing` for block (which will work well in chrome and FF):

```css
.main_block{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background:#888;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black inset;
}
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inner border to *cover* the border of the parent element, use these settings:

```
 .block{
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

The position by default is *inside* the border of the parent. The above settings move it onto the border of the parent (one pixel up and to the left), thereby covering it.

Here is a snippet containing this:

```css
.main_block{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  background:#888;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.block{
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```